# Determine which submit button clicked when they have same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with multiple submit buttons called "select". I want to be able to tell which was clicked. I can't set the value to the number because I want them to say "select". How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give them different `name` attributes instead of different `value` attributes. For example:

```
<%= f.submit "select", name: "select_one" %>
<%= f.submit "select", name: "select_two" %>
```

Clicking the first one will insert

```
"select_one"=>"select"
```

into your `POST` parameters and clicking the second one will insert

```
"select_two"=>"select"
```

into your `POST` parameters.

In your controller, simply use `params[:select_one]` and/or `params[:select_two]` as conditions in your logic, like so:

```
if params[:select_one]
  puts "select_one was clicked"
elsif params[:select_two]
  puts "select_two was clicked"
end
```

Comment: was hoping there was another way but this worked. thanks.